# JavaScript - Unable to get property from an Array of Object over function(parameters)

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of Objects:

```
var keywordset = [
    {word:["PO","Pending Order"],message:["Do you need to post registry?"]},
    {word:["delete"],message:["Do you want to delete in system?"]},
    {word:["contact"],message:["Inter-related feature: Contact Management"]}
]
```

Also, I created a function to convert the strings in an array of objects to UpperCase:

```
function ObjectArrayUpperCase(arrayname,array1){
console.log(arrayname[0])
console.log(array1)
for(b=0;b<arrayname.length;b++){
    for(c=0;c<arrayname[b].array1.length;c++){
        arrayname[b].array1[c] = arrayname[b].array1[c].toUpperCase()
      }
    }
}
```

Then, i run the `ObjectArrayUpperCase()` function by passing parameter into it

```
ObjectArrayUpperCase(keywordset,'word')
```

Unfortunately, the `ObjectArrayUpperCase()` function unable to process "array1" part, seems like unable to recognize it. But the "arrayname" working as expected, because if i replace "array1" to "word", the function work.

I tried to change the parameter but still no luck:

```
ObjectArrayUpperCase(keywordset,'word')
ObjectArrayUpperCase(keywordset,word)
ObjectArrayUpperCase(keywordset,keywordset.word)
etc...
```

Please advise how to pass the correct parameter to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need square brackets to evaluate an expression like `array1` to be used as the property name.

```
for(var b=0;b<arrayname.length;b++) {
    // -----------------------v------v--- and likewise below
    for(var c=0;c<arrayname[b][array1].length;c++){
        arrayname[b][array1][c] = arrayname[b][array1][c].toUpperCase()
      }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, how could it know if you meant to use the variable or an actual property with that name?

Also, be sure to declare your variables explicitly. I used `var` above.

Lastly, the loops can be written a little more cleanly using modern syntax and methods like this:

```
arrayname.forEach(obj => obj[array1] = obj[array1].map(s => s.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: But why .array1 is not working? my understanding is it will just turn to .word...

Comment: @Jerry: I explain it the sentence below the first code example.

Comment: @Jerry Please, mark the question as accepted if it works for you so that other people can reference it in the future.

Comment: i think that time i did check the tick, but seems like got time limit or it didn't reflect accordingly..